# Tips on multiple key Map-wrapper

Tags: java, generics

I'm creating a simple generic `Map`-wrapper with multiple keyed values.

I'm intending to use it with storing edges in a graph, where an edge goes from one vertex to another. Thus, I can fetch any of the two vertices in constant time instead of having to loop to find either to/from.

```
public class MultiMap<K1 extends Object, K2 extends Object, V extends Object> {

    private Map<K1, V> map1;
    private Map<K2, V> map2;

    /**
     * @param map1
     * @param map2
     */
    public MultiMap() {
        this.map1 = new HashMap<K1, V>();
        this.map2 = new HashMap<K2, V>();
    }

    public void put(K1 key1, K2 key2, V value) {
        this.map1.put(key1, value);
        this.map2.put(key2, value);
    }

    ...

    public V removeByKey1(K1 key) {
        V res = this.map1.remove(key);
        K2 k = null;
        for (Map.Entry<K2, V> entry : this.map2.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() == res) {
                k = entry.getKey();
                break;
            }
        }
        this.map2.remove(k);
        return res;
    }

    public V removeByKey2(K2 key) {
        V res = this.map2.remove(key);
        K1 k = null;
        for (Map.Entry<K1, V> entry : this.map1.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() == res) {
                k = entry.getKey();
                break;
            }
        }
        this.map1.remove(k);
        return res;
    }

    ...
}
```

Is there better way of removing? E.g. using `LinkedHashMap` and then using the key index to do it in constant time instead of linear?

If there's something else not sitting right with you, tell me. All feedback appreciated.

Comment: I would use an adjacency matrix, or sparse adjacency matrix.

Comment: You can use the Guava Collection Table (https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table), even the site example refers to what you want to do! :)

Comment: I've had a brain fart. If you have read the comment where I explain the class's purpose above, the edge from vertex a to b is different from vertex b to a. Since the keys refer to same vertex, it doesn't work out. I'll look into Guava and adjacency matrixes!

Answer (score 2):

Some notes about the current code:

1. `extends Objects` looks unnecessary in the class declaration:

   ```
   public class MultiMap<K1 extends Object, K2 extends Object, V extends Object> {
   ```

   I'm not completely sure but the following seems to be the same:

   ```
   public class MultiMap<K1, K2, V> {
   ```
2. I'd rename `res` to `oldValue` or something more descriptive.
3. Modern IDEs use highlighting to separate local variables from fields, so don't need to use `this.`. It's rather noise.
4. Comments like this are just noise:

   ```
    /**
    * @param map1
    * @param map2
    */
   ```

   It doesn't say anything more than the code says. Furthermore, the constructor does not have any parameter like `map1` or `map2`. (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: *Chapter 4: Comments, Noise Comments*)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: create a compound class which stores both `key1` and `key2` and put this into the maps as value. With that `remove` will be iteration-free.

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Maps.newHashMap;

import java.util.Map;

public class MultiMap<K1, K2, V> {

    private final Map<K1, CompoundValue<K1, K2, V>> map1 =
            newHashMap();
    private final Map<K2, CompoundValue<K1, K2, V>> map2 =
            newHashMap();

    public MultiMap() {
    }

    public void put(final K1 key1, final K2 key2, final V value) {
        final CompoundValue<K1, K2, V> compoundValue =
                new CompoundValue<K1, K2, V>(key1, key2, value);
        map1.put(key1, compoundValue);
        map2.put(key2, compoundValue);
    }

    public V removeByKey1(final K1 key1) {
        final CompoundValue<K1, K2, V> oldCompoundValue =
                map1.remove(key1);
        map2.remove(oldCompoundValue.key2);

        return oldCompoundValue.value;
    }

    public V removeByKey2(final K2 key2) {
        final CompoundValue<K1, K2, V> oldCompoundValue =
                map2.remove(key2);
        map1.remove(oldCompoundValue.key1);
        return oldCompoundValue.value;
    }

    private static class CompoundValue<K1, K2, V> {
        private final K1 key1;
        private final K2 key2;
        private final V value;

        public CompoundValue(final K1 key1, final K2 key2, 
                final V value) {
            this.key1 = key1;
            this.key2 = key2;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

`newHashMap` is from Google Guava.